# Content of root's home directory in OSX

Tags: osx, root, home

What is stored in root's home directory on OSX? What happens if you delete it on accident?

Here's what's in my current root home folder.

```
OSX:~ root# ls -lash
total 8
0 drwxr-x---   5 root  wheel   170B Nov 14 03:40 .
0 drwxr-xr-x  25 root  wheel   850B Nov 14 11:42 ..
8 -rw-r--r--   1 root  wheel     3B Nov 14 03:40 .CFUserTextEncoding
0 -r--r--r--   1 root  wheel    10B Jun 28  2014 .forward
0 drwx------  10 root  wheel   340B Mar 21 10:13 Library
```

Here's what's in the Library

```
OSX:~ root# ls -lash Library
total 0
0 drwx------  10 root  wheel   340B Mar 21 10:13 .
0 drwxr-x---   5 root  wheel   170B Nov 14 03:40 ..
0 -r--r--r--   1 root  wheel     0B Aug 24  2013 .localized
0 drwx------+  3 root  wheel   102B Dec 11 16:22 Application Support
0 drwxr-xr-x  11 root  wheel   374B Dec 11 16:21 Caches
0 drwxr-xr-x   3 root  wheel   102B Mar 21 10:14 Cookies
0 drwxr-xr-x   3 root  wheel   102B Nov 14 03:43 Dictionaries
0 drwx------   3 root  wheel   102B Mar 21 10:13 Logs
0 drwx------  24 root  wheel   816B Mar 26 15:13 Preferences
0 drwx------   2 root  wheel    68B Nov 14 11:34 Saved Application State
```

Comment: Looks just like the `~/Library` directory structure of any other user on MacOS, nothing specific to `root` here.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing special. The root user is not an administrative clerk or business manager. You could probably keep it permanently removed and nothing amazing would happen.